# Is there any way to find out the size / sizes of your database tables?

Tags: sql-server, size

i've got around 10 tables in my sql 2008 server.

Currently, my mdf is around 3.5Gig. (I also have some binary data in some of the tables). So, I'm wondering if there's a way i could see which tables are the biggest in size.

Is this possible?

Maybe it's an index or FTS catalog instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run this:

```
/******************************************************************************
**    File: “GetTableSpaceUseage.sql”
**    Name: Get Table Space Useage for a specific schema
**    Auth: Robert C. Cain
**    Date: 01/27/2008
**
**    Desc: Calls the sp_spaceused proc for each table in a schema and returns
**        the Table Name, Number of Rows, and space used for each table.
**
**    Called by:
**     n/a – As needed
**
**    Input Parameters:
**     In the code check the value of @schemaname, if you need it for a
**     schema other than dbo be sure to change it.
**
**    Output Parameters:
**     NA
*******************************************************************************/

/*—————————————————————————*/
/* Drop the temp table if it's there from a previous run                     */
/*—————————————————————————*/
if object_id(N'tempdb..[#TableSizes]') is not null
  drop table #TableSizes ;
go

/*—————————————————————————*/
/* Create the temp table                                                     */
/*—————————————————————————*/
create table #TableSizes
  (
    [Table Name] nvarchar(128)   /* Name of the table */
  , [Number of Rows] char(11)    /* Number of rows existing in the table. */
  , [Reserved Space] varchar(18) /* Reserved space for table. */
  , [Data Space] varchar(18)    /* Amount of space used by data in table. */
  , [Index Size] varchar(18)    /* Amount of space used by indexes in table. */
  , [Unused Space] varchar(18)   /* Amount of space reserved but not used. */
  ) ;
go

/*—————————————————————————*/
/* Load the temp table                                                        */
/*—————————————————————————*/
declare @schemaname varchar(256) ;
-- Make sure to set next line to the Schema name you want!
set @schemaname = 'dbo' ;

-- Create a cursor to cycle through the names of each table in the schema
declare curSchemaTable cursor
  for select sys.schemas.name + '.' + sys.objects.name
      from    sys.objects
            , sys.schemas
      where   object_id > 100
              and sys.schemas.name = @schemaname
              /* For a specific table uncomment next line and supply name */
              --and sys.objects.name = 'specific-table-name-here'    
              and type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
              and sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id ;

open curSchemaTable ;
declare @name varchar(256) ;  /* This holds the name of the current table*/

-- Now loop thru the cursor, calling the sp_spaceused for each table
fetch curSchemaTable into @name ;
while ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
  begin    
    insert into #TableSizes
            exec sp_spaceused @objname = @name ;       
    fetch curSchemaTable into @name ;   
  end

/* Important to both close and deallocate! */
close curSchemaTable ;     
deallocate curSchemaTable ;


/*—————————————————————————*/
/* Feed the results back                                                     */
/*—————————————————————————*/
select [Table Name]
      , [Number of Rows]
      , [Reserved Space]
      , [Data Space]
      , [Index Size]
      , [Unused Space]
from    [#TableSizes]
order by [Table Name] ;

/*—————————————————————————*/
/* Remove the temp table                                                     */
/*—————————————————————————*/
drop table #TableSizes ;
```

[taken](http://arcanecode.com/2008/01/28/getting-table-space-usage-in-sql-server-2005/) from [Robert Caine](http://arcanecode.com/) blog

Edited the code to parse, several chars that were in single quote used a special single quote, as well the -- sign.

This code is for Microsoft SQL 2005+

Comment: Is this script for Microsoft Sql Server? I get a score of errors when i parse-check it.

Comment: found out that single quotes and double dashes were in special font, all done now and all you need is copy/past and execute... see the comments in the code to change schema/table

Comment: i'll award this one because it's a nice mix of verbose and not tooooo much info. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

```
exec sp_spaceused [tablename]
```

Comment: Good call on the square brackets. It never fails, I use the angle brackets, forget to indent, and they disappear. grrr. When is the internet gonna finally know what I'm trying to do?

Comment: what's the diff between square brackets and angled brackets (with Josh's answer, above) ?

Comment: i'm not sure about angled brackets, but the square brackets enable "funny" table names (reserved words, spaces in table names, etc...)

Answer (score 6):

[sys.allocations_units](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189792.aspx) has the information you need. You join with [sys.partitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175012.aspx) to group all allocation units of a partition together and also to obtain the more usable object_id rather than the esoteric allocation_unit_id.

```
select object_name(p.object_id),
    sum(au.total_pages)*8 as [space_in_kb]
    from sys.partitions p
    join sys.allocation_units au on p.hobt_id = au.container_id
    group by p.object_id
    order by [space_in_kb]  desc
```

And yes, all tables (heap or clustered) are '`partitions`', the terms does not refer to partitioned tables. sys.partitions also has the 'rows' column that may interest you.

Comment: this is a great script for a single summary :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 exec sp_spaceused <tablename>
```

Comment: using this without parameters will get your database size, index sizes, etc. 

if given with ie. exec sp_spaceused 'sometable'. It will give you row count, data size and index size of the table

Comment: what's the difference between RESERVED and DATA, please?

Comment: reserved is disk space reserved for table. data is total amount of space used by data in table.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL 2008+: right-click on the DB name in SSMS, select `Reports`, then `Standard Reports`, then `Disk Usage by Table`.

Answer (score 3):

This query shows the size of each table in the current database.

```
SELECT sysobjects.[name] AS [TableName],
    SUM(sysindexes.reserved) * 8 AS [Size(KB)],
    SUM(sysindexes.dpages) * 8 AS [Data(KB)],
    (SUM(sysindexes.used) - SUM(sysindexes.dpages)) * 8 AS [Indexes(KB)],
    (SUM(sysindexes.reserved) - SUM(sysindexes.dpages)) * 8 AS [Unused(KB)]
FROM dbo.sysindexes AS sysindexes
    JOIN dbo.sysobjects AS sysobjects ON sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
WHERE sysobjects.[type] = 'U'
GROUP BY sysobjects.[name]
ORDER BY [Size(KB)] DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I run this... It gets all tables to temp table, loops it through and gets sizes for all tables. Result data is in @tablesizes, so you can query it how you like.

Works in Sql Server >2005

```
declare @tables TABLE
(
    table_name nvarchar(200)
)

declare @tablesizes TABLE
(
    [name] nvarchar(200),
    [rows] int,
    reserved nvarchar(200),
    data nvarchar(200),
    index_size nvarchar(200),
    unused nvarchar(200),
    reserved_int int,
    data_int int,
    index_size_int int,
    unused_int int
)

declare @t nvarchar(200)

insert into @tables
select Table_Name from information_schema.tables

while exists(select * from @tables)
begin
    set @t=(select top 1 table_name from @tables)

    insert into @tablesizes([name],[rows],reserved,data,index_size,unused)
    exec sp_spaceused @t

    delete top (1) from @tables
end

update @tablesizes set 
reserved_int=convert(int, replace(reserved,' KB','')),
data_int=convert(int, replace(data,' KB','')),
index_size_int=convert(int, replace(index_size,' KB','')),
unused_int=convert(int, replace(unused,' KB',''))

select * from @tablesizes order by data_int desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT @@servername;

IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#spaceUsed%')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #spaceUsed;
    END;
CREATE TABLE #spaceUsed  (
name VARCHAR(255) ,
rows INT ,
reserved VARCHAR(50) ,
data VARCHAR(50) ,
index_size VARCHAR(50) ,
unused VARCHAR(50));

EXEC sp_msforeachtable
@command1 =' 
--
INSERT INTO #spaceUsed
exec sp_spaceused N''?'';
'
,@whereand = ' And Object_id In (Select Object_id From sys.objects
Where SCHEMA_NAME(Schema_ID) like ''%'')';

DECLARE
   @spaceUsedData TABLE  (
   name VARCHAR(255) ,
   rows INT ,
   reservedMB BIGINT NULL ,
   dataMB BIGINT NULL ,
   index_sizeMB BIGINT NULL ,
   unusedMB BIGINT NULL);

INSERT INTO INTO @spaceUsedData (name , rows , reservedMB , dataMB ,index_sizeMB ,unusedMB)
SELECT                  name , rows ,
Convert ( BIGINT ,Ltrim(Rtrim(Replace(reserved ,'KB' ,'')) ))/1024 ,
Convert ( BIGINT ,Ltrim(Rtrim(Replace(data ,'KB' ,'')) ))/1024 ,
Convert ( BIGINT ,Ltrim(Rtrim(Replace(index_size ,'KB' ,'')) ))/1024 ,
Convert ( BIGINT ,Ltrim(Rtrim(Replace(unused ,'KB' ,'')) ))/1024
FROM #spaceUsed;

SELECT * , reservedMB+  dataMB+index_sizeMB+unusedMB AS TotalMB FROM @spaceUsedData
ORDER BY rows DESC;
```